# dynamically creating a custom view: Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to dynamically create a custom view (i.e. without any XML file). Here is my class :

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {
    Context context;

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addInfo(String path, String text){
        ImageView photo = new ImageView(context);
        photo.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset(context,path));
        this.addView(photo);

        TextView name = new TextView(context);
        name.setText(text);
        this.addView(name);
    }
}
```

And in my Main :

```
LinearLayout container = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

MyCustomView cv = new MyCustomView(getApplicationContext());
cv.addInfo("myPath","myText");
container.addView(cv);
```

But I get the following exception one the `addView`: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0`

I guess something has not been correctly initialized...

**- EDIT - 
I made a mistake mimatching the content on one of my Text where I was trying to put and int... and somehow it did not crash at build time but only at run time**

Comment: There's way more to that stacktrace.

Comment: You have to give path to the resource folder.

Comment: on which line you have this error ?

Comment: on the `addView` in the `addInfo`. Any of the two (I tried to comment the first one)

Comment: Are you actually passing "myPath" and "myText"? Those are placeholders. If you actually have image assets, you need to specify a real filename, not just "myPath"

Comment: An example of `myPath` value?

Comment: Your comment put me on the track to find the bug. thanks